# How to reset data in previous view controller?

Tags: iphone

I am using multiple view controllers associated with a corresponding tab.

I need to be able to move from  tab2 to  tab1 and to initialize my previous view controller associated with tab1 just as if I had open the tab for the  first time when app launches. However, it does not initialize it like I expect when I switch tabs. This is what I have tried:.
In my view controller1, I have table data that has navigation to another ViewController. I applied changes to view will disappear but no result.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated  
{  
          appDelegate.select = nil;        
          [tableCat reloadData];  
           NSLog(@"hello");  
}
```

Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `viewWillAppear:` method instead to initialize the view how you want it. This method is called before it is actually shown, so it should do what you want.

Comment: +1 This will work for this case, and most others, perfectly. The caveat being a modal popover when dismissed does not result in `viewWillAppear:` being called. Just something to keep in mind if you plan to reuse your view controller elsewhere.